# Make selenium driver wait, on nothing, for x seconds

Tags: java, selenium

How can I make the selenium driver in Java wait on nothing for a few seconds, just to pause the driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply do `Thread.sleep(1000)` to sleep for 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to wait using selenium:

- [Explicit Waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits): wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

This waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException or if it finds the element will return it in 0 - 10 seconds

- [Implicit waits](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits): An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available.

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
    WebElement myDynamicElement = driver.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
```

Also you can use Thread.sleep(), this is not recommended but if you are just debugging this is the easiest way.

You can take a look to the [Selenium documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) to understand better how to use waits.

Answer (score 0):

```
 try {
                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
fun WebDriver.delay(timeout: Duration) {
    val until = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout.toMillis()

    WebDriverWait(this, timeout).until {
        return@until until <= System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
}
```

It's kotlin extendsions code. normally method like this:

```kotlin
fun delay(driver: WebDriver, timeout: Duration) {
    val until = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeout.toMillis()

    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until {
        return@until until <= System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using in Python

```
import time

print "Start : %s" % time.ctime()
time.sleep( 5 )
print "End : %s" % time.ctime()
```

Output :

```
Start : Tue Feb 17 10:19:18 2009
End : Tue Feb 17 10:19:23 2009
```